# removing redundancy from regex with multiple possible delimiters

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a regex in which the same match criteria can apply to multiple delimiters.  `[]`, `()`, and `<>` are all valid.  For example purposes it looks like this:

`\[.\]|\(.\)|<.>`

Is there some way to remove the redundancy from the above regex?  The match criteria inside the delimiters is always the same, but the delimiters themselves may be different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're asking because

```
[[(<].[])>]
```

isn't exact enough, for obvious reasons.

It's always dangerous to answer, "No, there is no way," because it's hard to be sure one has checked every possible way. One must often come up with a solid proof to answer in such cases.

I'm not sure this is a strong-enough proof, or even a "proof" at all, but consider this (pseudo-)information-theory perspective:

1. The PCRE engine itself has no knowledge of any relation between the pairs of characters, `[]`, `()`, and `<>`. Thus, the expression itself must contain that information, *i.e.* require *at least* the six characters `[]()<>` to be present.
2. Not only that, but for the same reason, the expression itself must define *at least* two *pairings* (leaving the third to be implied). I'm not sure how to prove that two alternation operators (`|`) is the best you can do, but I mean, even if there *were* a more compact way, you're going to save one character *at most*, since at least one bit is required to say, "Pairings exist!"
3. The escaping of meta-characters can only be compacted by the fact that `[]()` can appear within character classes without being escaped, but firstly, that isn't really a "removal of redundancy" as much as it is "a lucky circumstance in syntax", and secondly, you still have to add two characters for the definition of said character class: `[]`.
4. Therefore, it is my belief that even from a theoretical perspective, if my presumptions about what a regex engine *cannot know* are true, then one can save *at most* three characters from the regex you've already provided: `\[.\]|\(.\)|<.>`.

I eagerly look forward to being corrected by the regex gurus!

Answer (score 1):

If you really are using the [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) (via PHP, for example) you can use a DEFINE group to create a subroutine, like so:

```
'~(?(DEFINE)(?<content>\w+))(?:<(?&content)>|\[(?&content)\]|\((?&content)\))~'
```

...or more readably:

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<content>\w+))
(?:
  <(?&content)>
  |
  \[(?&content)\]
  |
  \((?&content)\)
)
```

Here's a **[demo](http://ideone.com/F2zYM)** in PHP. It should work in Perl, too.